# Access - Form Value Usage Optimization

Tags: ms-access, coding-style, vba

Say I use a value, `ME!txtUsername.value` throughout an event, and pass it through to many functions. 
Is it more efficient or best practice to:

A) Set The Value Into A Variable

```
DIM username as string
username = ME!txtUsername.value
```

OR

B) Use It Explicitly Through The Event

```
DIM username as string
iAmAFunction(ME!txtUsername.value)
```

OR

C) There is a negligible difference and it is simply preference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the faster way for retrieving the same value multiple times would be to assign it to a variable the first time and retrieve it from the variable thereafter.

But, I suspect you would need a fairly extreme border case to actually notice a difference.  So I'll say the correct answer is *C - negligible difference*.

Personally, I wouldn't be concerned about a performance difference with this.  I would likely prefer to repeatedly type and read `strUsername` instead of  `ME!txtUsername.value`

My gut reaction is this is a micro-optimization which is seldom worth worrying about.

Comment: Seems like a pretty good answer. Given its access retrieving it from the control everytime might actually be faster because access doesnt behave in normal ways, but I certainly agree with your conclusion re C.

Comment: @JohnBingham  My take is Access must first examine the form's `Controls` collection to find the one named `txtUsername` and then retrieve its `.Value` property.  Although those look-ups are nearly instantaneous, I guessed they would still take more time than retrieving the value of a variable.  If you have a persuasive counter-argument, I'm interested.  Anyway we both agree on *C*.  :-)

Comment: My worries with pushing it into a variable would be the creation\destruction of the variable being passed to other functions. (Pending if it is by reference or not), on the contrary, the Controls collection is already sitting in memory and is quick to grasp, I assume?

Comment: Hmm.  Seems to me the issue about altering the value in a procedure should be dealt with by passing it `ByVal` or `ByRef` as needed.  As for the raw performance impact ... try it both ways and see whether you can detect a difference.  :-)

Comment: Sorry if I sound dismissive about this; but I guess I am kind of.  I place a greater emphasis on developer productivity than I do on chasing micro-optimizations.

Comment: Agreed, this is more an exercise of curiosity.